# Apache Shiro - authentication with attribute other than cn?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, shiro

I'm trying to use Apache Shiro in our project for authentication and authorization with an Active Directory realm. It works good when I authenticate with the users CN attribute however, I would like to use another unique attribute for login. Is it possible to configure shiro to do so?

Here is my shiro.ini file:

```
    [main]
    shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp
    activeDirectoryRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryRealm
    activeDirectoryRealm.systemUsername = admin
    activeDirectoryRealm.systemPassword = secret
    activeDirectoryRealm.searchBase = DC=company,DC=private
    activeDirectoryRealm.url = ldap://url:389
```

And the login code:

```java
    public void login(String uname, String pwd, boolean rememberMe) {
            Factory<SecurityManager> ldapFactory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
            SecurityManager sManager = ldapFactory.getInstance();
            SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(sManager);
            Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
            if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
                uname = "CN=" + uname + ",OU=Users";
                UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(uname, pwd);
                token.setRememberMe(rememberMe);
                try {
                    currentUser.login(token);
                } catch (UnknownAccountException ex) {
                    logger.info("Unknown user");
                } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ex) {
                    logger.info("Incorrect credentials");
                } catch (LockedAccountException ex) {
                    logger.info("Account is locked");
                } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

If i change the line

```java
    uname = "CN=" + uname + ",OU=Users";
```

to the following

```java
    uname = "myCustomAttribute=" + uname + ",OU=Users";
```

and try to login with it, I got

```
    javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1 ]
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've managed to do this by creating a custom MyJndiLdapRealm extending JndiLdapRealm and overriding method

```
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token){}
```

but I still welcome answers if you have better solutions.